# How to Reverse SSRS Recursive Hierarchy Sorting from Parent-Child to Child-Parent

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to reverse the sorting of a recursive hierarchy in a report in SSRS 200R2. The report is built over an SSAS cube that contains the required hierarchy.

I read the answers to this topic:
[SSRS ignores sort in a recursive hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284396/ssrs-ignores-sort-in-a-recursive-hierarchy) and I understood that I can't sort the hierarchy between levels. However, what I want to do is reverse the sorting from Parent-Child to Child-Parent, rather than the sorting between levels, and I can't find a way to do it.

Here's an example of what I mean:

A recursive hierarchy of employees and a summed measure appears likes this:

```
Employee | Measure
------------------
Peter    | 10
  Adam   | 3
  Zelda  | 7
James    | 20
  Becky  | 15
  Paul   | 5
```

I'd like to see the same information, but I want to have the children appear at the top and the parent at the bottom of its group:

```
Employee | Measure
------------------
  Adam   | 3
  Zelda  | 7
Peter    | 10
  Becky  | 15
  Paul   | 5
James    | 20
```

I tried adding a new field, "employee_level", that represents the level of the employee in the employee hierarchy that I've used to create the report, but sorting the tablix by "employee_level" did nothing.

Here is the query I used in MDX to get the above output:

```
WITH  
SET Filter_Employee_Hierarchy AS 
FILTER ([Employees].[Emp_Id].ALLMEMBERS , [Measures].[Sum] > 0)

MEMBER Employee_Level AS
[Employees].[Emp_Id].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 

MEMBER Employee AS
[Employees].[Emp_Id].MEMBER_CAPTION

MEMBER Employee_Parent AS 
[Employees].[Emp_Id].PARENT.MEMBER_CAPTION

SELECT 
{ [Measures].[Sum], Employee_Level, Employee,Employee_Parent } ON COLUMNS, 
{ Filter_Employee_Hierarchy } ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube];
```

Is it possible to achieve the above reversal? If so, how?

edit:
What I'm trying to do is to get the reverse order in the **SSRS report**. Adding ORDER to the MDX isn't effecting the end report.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `ORDER` function within the `SELECT` clause?

```
WITH  
SET [Filter_Employee_Hierarchy] AS 
  FILTER (
    [Employees].[Emp_Id].ALLMEMBERS 
  , [Measures].[Sum] > 0 
  )
SET [Filter_Employee_Hierarchy_ORDERED] AS
 ORDER(
    HIERARCHIZE([Filter_Employee_Hierarchy])
   ,[Measures].[Employee_Level]
   ,BDESC  
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[RNKforOrdering] AS
  RANK(
     [Employees].[Emp_Id].CURRENTMEMBER
    ,[Filter_Employee_Hierarchy_ORDERED]
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[Employee_Level] AS
  [Employees].[Emp_Id].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
MEMBER [Measures].[Employee] AS
  [Employees].[Emp_Id].MEMBER_CAPTION
MEMBER [Measures].[Employee_Parent] AS 
  [Employees].[Emp_Id].PARENT.MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT 
  { 
    [Measures].[Sum]
  , [Measures].[Employee_Level] 
  , [Measures].[Employee_Parent] 
  , [Measures].[RNKforOrdering]
  } ON 0, 
  [Filter_Employee_Hierarchy_ORDERED] ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm afraid it didn't help much. While it changed the MDX results, the SSRS report still shows parent-child in that order.

Comment: maybe we could add a measure that reflects the desired order and then use that to order by inside ssrs?

Comment: @NicoleVardi I see a mention of OU in your profile - do you work or teach with the OU? I'm currently preparing for TM354 exam - hence some deserved procrastination time via Stackoverflow!

Comment: I'm actually a student at OU, faily my way through a science degree myself :) 
RE the measure, I tried that when I had the "employee_level" added. Once I have the grouping defined as Recursive Hierarchy, SSRS just ignores me :(